# Session is not getting renewed

Tags: session, invalid

Some facts about our implementation:

1. There is 10 seconds frequency to access the SFDC web service.
2. We create a singleton session at the start of the app.
3. We implemented the SessionRenewer interface to renew the session in
   case of "INVALID SESSION" issue. We are having a Quartz scheduler
   which uses
       the SFDC webservice(s) to retrieve data.

Problem statement
Once in a while we get the Invalid session from SFDC at that time session renewer renew the session but somehow we still get INVALID SESSION error in our subsequent calls and eventually we need to bump the server.